# How to STOP JSF validation on p:calendar when it is not required field?

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, calendar

I have the following date field

```
<p:calendar id="sampleDate"                 
    value="#{sampleController.sampleDate}" 
    navigator="true" showOn="button" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" converterMessage="Sample date is not valid" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"/>
```

everything works as expected but this is not the required field but when i submit the page with wrong value in this field like **11/11** JSF validates and gives me error message **Sample date is not valid**

I have handled some validations for this date field in **Controller** .

So how do i stop this validation when the wrong value is given like **11/11** as this validation is taken care in Controller.

I need this validation because this field is not required field.

Comment: If I understand correct you don't want validation in client side because you have your validation in the controller. So you want to pass the validation for the calendar?

Comment: You can jump the validation phase using immediate="true".

Comment: @MychellTeixeira immediate = "true" is good solution when we do not want the value at the server side but my case is different. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: So, why do you want to have an invalid date even be send to the server? Client validation is to avoid this :P

Comment: _"immediate = "true" is good solution when we do not want the value at the server side"_ This is not correct

Comment: @Kukeltje,  i have commented on this long time ago and getting some **** now :-p